# How to calculate energy from power I receive every 5 minutes

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, energy, solar-energy

I  have to calculate energy from power measurements, which I receive every 5 minutes. The values are summed and assigned to measurements, then monthly measurements and finally yearly measurements. Having that aggregates of power measurements, the question is if I can calculate energy in kWh unit by equation:

energy_sum = power_sum * (5/60) / 1000

as I want to convert 5 min to hours and W to kW.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321963/how-to-calculate-electrical-energy-consumed?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C71.1772

Comment: Your calculation is correct PROVIDED THAT the 5  minute power reading properly represents the average power over the 5 minute period. Telling us how the per 5 minute figure is Driver at would help us to help you better.

Comment: The power reading, as you notice, represents the average power over the 5 minute period. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @ytyr HOW is the power averaged over the 5 minute period? What is the power source being measured. What you are saying is that you receive a scaled kWh energy reading once every 5 minutes with scale factor =  1/12. Whether this represents true energy over this period depends on how it was calculated. Telling us more will quite possibly help us to provide you with a better answer.